# xml to csv get elements from different roots in single row using xsl

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I want to convert below xml to csv using xsl. My challenge is i have to get elements from different roots and in sequence

```
<root>
    <child1>
        <value1>100</value1>
    </child1>
    <child1>
            <value1>200</value1>
    </child1>
    <child2>
        <value2>300</value2>
    </child2>
    <child2>
         <value2>400</value2>
    </child2>
</root>
```

expected output is :

```
child1,child2
100,300
200,400
```

Does anyone know how can we achieve this using xslt?

Comment: Is the count of `<child1>` and `<child2>` nodes same in the input XML?

Comment: yes count is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below XSLT to get the desired output

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />   

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:variable name="countChild1" select="count(child1)" />
        <xsl:variable name="countChild2" select="count(child2)" />
        <xsl:variable name="column1" select="local-name(child1)" />
        <xsl:variable name="column2" select="local-name(child2)" />

        <!-- Print header row -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$column1" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$column2" />
        <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>

        <!-- Print values -->
        <xsl:if test="$countChild1 = $countChild2">
            <xsl:for-each select="child1">
                <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()" />
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../child2[$index])" />
                <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
child1,child2
100,300
200,400
```